# Dynamically add form fields

Tags: php, cakephp

I have problem with dynamiccaly adding form fields in CakePHP app and I don't know how to solve it. I want to have form in EventsController/add.ctp for add Event where I want to have fields Events.name, Dates.from, Dates.to, Dates.endregister, Dates.location_id, {optional more Dates.from, Dates.to, ...}, Terms_mem.teacher_id {and optional more Terms_mem.teacher_id} My tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`name` varchar(150) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `dates` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`from` datetime NOT NULL,
`to` datetime NOT NULL,
`endregister` datetime,
`event_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`location_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `events`(`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `locations`(`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `locations` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`street` varchar(70),
`city` varchar(70) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `dates_mem` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`teacher_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`date_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (`teacher_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`date_id`) REFERENCES `dates`(`id`)
)
```

So form would look like:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Event'); ?>
<fieldset>
<?php
    // events
    echo $this->Form->input('name');
    // dates
    echo $this->Form->input('from');
    echo $this->Form->input('to');
    echo $this->Form->input('endregister');
    echo $this->Form->input('location_id');

    /* HERE optional dynamically add next inputs for dates (from, to, ...) */

    // teachers
    echo $this->Form->input('teacher_id');

    /* HERE optional dynamically add next inputs for teachers(teacher_id) */
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

And after all that fields save to corresponding tables. Is this possible in CakePHP, version 2.4? If yes, could you help me with it?

EDIT:

burzum wrote:

```
$this->Form->input('Date.0.from');
$this->Form->input('Date.0.to');
$this->Form->input('Date.1.from');
$this->Form->input('Date.1.to');
```

Is it possible to do it as: ? Thus fields Date.1.from and Date.1.to add to form dynamically after click on button add next date

```
$this->Form->input('Date.0.from');
$this->Form->input('Date.0.to');
// button add next date
$this->Form->input('Date.1.from'); // after click on add next date
$this->Form->input('Date.1.to');   // after click on add next date
// button add next date
$this->Form->input('Date.2.from'); // after click on add next date
$this->Form->input('Date.2.to');   // after click on add next date
// button add next date
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to read the manual? If not read the manual it is explained there in detail in the section "[Saving your data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)". See [this part](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto).

In short, first the view

```
$this->Form->input('FirstModel.field1');
$this->Form->input('SecondModel.field1');
$this->Form->input('SecondModel.field2');
$this->Form->input('Date.0.from');
$this->Form->input('Date.0.to');
$this->Form->input('Date.1.from');
$this->Form->input('Date.1.to');
// ...
```

Controller:

```
$this->saveAll($this->request->data);
```

Yes, you can add fields dynamically on the fly, use Javascript to inject additional fields into the DOM. Either via a JS template or via AJAX. Just make sure the form inputs you generate follow the CakePHP conventions and that you white list the JS generated fields. Also make sure you validate the inputs you've white listed very strict to avoid getting things added you don't want. You should use the security component if you don't use it already.

Comment: Updated my answer as well.